# Element not recognized on page until a manual click on the page occurs

Tags: java, selenium

I am searching for an element on a webpage by using its XPath.  The XPath is correct and can find the element ONLY if I manually perform a click anywhere on the page first.  If I do not do this before the statement runs it will not find the element.

I have tried many different attempts to allow focus on the page:

```
selenium.selectWindow(null);
selenium.fireEvent(xpath, "focus");
selenium.click(element on page);
selenium.mouseDown();
selenium.mouseUp();
```

After performing these functions the statement will still not find the element, but if I manually maximize the page and click anywhere on the page, then run the statement, the element is found.  Can anyone help me out with this?

The statement I am using to find the element is:

```
selenium.isElementPresent("//div[@class='sample_class']");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using XPath, try using the CSS selector for that item.

Use `selenium.isElementPresent("css=div.sample_class");` as your selector. Saucelabs have explained it quite well at http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2009/10/selenium-tip-of-the-week-start-improving-your-locators/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am having the same issue using CSS selectors too.  I can find the element only after a manual click is performed on the page.  Without clicking on the page and executing the isElementPresent() method, it will return false.  Is there a way to make the element available without having to perform any manual steps?

Comment: can you show the markup of the page so we have a look and make suggestions from there